# How to operate several macs in different locations using one external hard drive 

Tags: mac, macbook, external-hard-drive

i operate from several different geographic locations ,regional and international  and do not want to carry around a macbook everywhere,  regionally i use a push bike so it gets too bulky with a macbook in my pack and i like the faster machines for graphics, i was thinking of using one  external portable ssd hard drive to keep all files in, especially the emails  using entourage or mail ,  and all the attached files with it.  a small light loaded enternal ssd in my pocket or backpack would be great.

Even better would be a set up where i could use anyones imac, macbook , power mac and boot it up using my ssd with  my mac home file located on it , and automatically used and saved to.

if this all can be done, then backup would be copying the ssd. as it will probably use firewire 800 can it copy by daisy chain two ssd externals and manually copying it all , or would there be some program that could back up only what in new or has been added too. i would need to occasionally transfer to archives old rarely used files to keep enough space free.

this is the dream, to always have all my data available .. in that one flexible ssd drive. 
can it be done ?  is it too hard ?

Comment: Any news on this? Would be interesting to know what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Install a full Mac OS X system on the external hard drive and boot from that on any machine. Not sure about hardware compatibility though (especially very new Macs)
- Create an Account and set its user directory to the external hard drive (`System Preferences`, `Accounts`, right-click an account to access `Advanced Options...`). Repeat for every Mac and you *should* be able to log in to the profile stored on the external disk.
- Move (some of) your files to the external disk and create symlinks to them from the internal disk. Might work with some applications, might not with others.
- Use a (local) folder syncing software. Sync before and after every computer change.

Answer (score 0):

you could image your home computers drive onto the external hard drive so to use "your mac" at somebody elses house you'd just have to boot off the drive. then to keep the home folders in sync use a folder sync utility when you're at home.  i don't know that you'd be able to use an ssd for that unless you have a buttload of money.

that's the simplest method i could come up with.